# Symfony API Platform 3: POST/PUT request passing in a DTO and getting a DTO back?

Tags: symfony, dto, api-platform.com

I'm upgrading an API Platform 2 project to API Platform 3 and the upgrade guide is clear on DataTransformers and DTOs (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/upgrade-guide): "Data transformers have been deprecated, instead you can still document the output or the input DTO. Then, just handle the input in a custom State Processor or return another output in a custom State Provider."

I've seen https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/ which provides three use cases for DTOs:

1. Implementing a Write Operation With an Input Different From the Resource
2. Implementing a Read Operation With an Output Different From the Resource
3. Implementing a Write Operation With an Output Different From the Resource

But our most common use case in API Platform 2 is DTO input > DataTransformer converts DTO to model/entity > Do the work on the model/entity > DataTransformer converts model/entity to DTO for output > DTO output

**So what I would have hoped to see was a use case when talking about DTOs under APIP3 that would handle 'Implementing a Write Operation With an Input Different From the Resource AND an Output Different From the Resource' - but this isn't described.**

Is this even possible under API Platform 3?

No combination of input/output/State Providers/State Processors seems to allow for this, and it feels like the most common use case, where we wrap the model/entity within a DTO for both input and output.

Can anyone help and tell me what I'm missing?

---

I can define **input **and a State Processor to convert the DTO into a model/entity using POST/PUT, but the response is a model/entity.

I can define **output** and a State Provider to convert the model/entity into a DTO using GET.

But I cannot define both an input and output DTO (the same DTO for input and output) but still do 'the work' on the model/entity that sits in the middle of this pipeline.